# Xcode 5.1 iOS 7.1 problems with cells at UITableView

Tags: uitableview, scroll, ios7.1, xcode5.1

I think I have found serious bug in new release of Xcode 5.1 after update my cells start to disappeare when I scroll to the bottom.

### [image]

When I press on them couple of them 
[image]

When I scroll after that to the top everything is fine and this problem is only on iOS 7.1. At iOS 7.0.3 everything is works fine.

[image]

I have found a little hack to make it work at iOS 7.1 To do that I have download old version of Xcode(5.0.2) and make build of application that I have install at my device with iOS 7.1 in this case everything is works fine too. So I think it's some bug in Xcode 5.1

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Im having the exact same problem with an app i was finalizing and things started to go crazy with the table views (all 3) right after the update..

found the solution 
[iOS 7.1 beta5 tableviewcell height showing objects outside it's range](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21632970/ios-7-1-beta5-tableviewcell-height-showing-objects-outside-its-range)

add the following to your cell

```
 cell.clipsToBounds =YES;
```

Answer (score 1):

I also had the same problem when I opened my project in Xcode 5.1 but I solved it in Interface Builder (Storyboard).

1. Click on the Table View Cell (not the Content View or Table View).
2. In the Inspector, check 'Clip Subviews'.
3. Do the same for all the other Table View Cells of the Table View.

[image: Clip Subviews]